# FlatMapIterable and empty lists

Tags: android, rx-java2

I want to execute a background task on a set of items from a database using RxJava 2. The list of items may be empty, which means I can't use flatMapIterable as it throws an exception on an empty list:

```
    Observable
            .fromCallable(() -> SQLite
                        .select()
                        .from(VideoUpload.class)
                        .where(VideoUpload_Table.status.eq(VIDEO_UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS))
                        .queryList())
            .flatMapIterable(videoUploads -> videoUploads)
            .map(videoUpload -> {
                videoUpload.setStatus(VIDEO_UPLOAD_NOT_STARTED);
                return videoUpload;
            })
            .firstElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(/* TODO */);
```

I can move everything into the callable, do the filtering there and so on, but I was thinking there may be a more elegant solution based on the code above.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, your only concern is that the source observable may be empty and you do not want to perform `filter` on the stream. Won't [`flatMapMaybe()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMapMaybe(io.reactivex.functions.Function)) be handy in this case?

Comment: Yes, I was considering using a Maybe, but I'm not sure how, do you have a suggestion? The concern is not only the filter, but the flatMapIterable as well, as it throws an exception if the incoming iterable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that flatMapIterable does not throw an exception on RxJava-2, I remember it throwing an exception on RxJava-1. Anyway, the way to do it is as follows

```
    Observable
            .fromCallable(() -> {
                List<VideoUpload> videos = SQLite
                        .select()
                        .from(VideoUpload.class)
                        .where(VideoUpload_Table.status.in(VIDEO_UPLOAD_IN_PROGRESS, VIDEO_UPLOAD_QUEUED))
                        .queryList();
                return videos;
            })
            .flatMapIterable(videoUploads -> videoUploads)
            .map(videoUpload -> {
                videoUpload.setStatus(VIDEO_UPLOAD_NOT_STARTED);
                return videoUpload;
            })
            .firstElement()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(/* TODO */);
```